# Motion sensor has attributes that seem to be invalid

Tags: zigbee, philips-hue

I am trying to figure out a problem with my Philips Hue Motion sensors. I have a ZigBee coordinator up and running, I have successfully joined the Motion Sensor to it and I have all Clusters and Attributes discovered. However, all the sensor values are constant. No actual change in conditions appears to cause any change to the values. Is there some particularly slow cycle on when the sensor values are updated? Is there something else blocking the sensor values from being correctly reported?

I'm hoping for some quick answer here as this should be rather straightforward behaviour.

Regardless I'll be setting up a sniffer to compare my coordinator to the Philips Hue Bridge network traffic to see if there is anything unique going on with the Hue Bridge as I suspect is the case.

Comment: Which attributes in particular are you watching? How are you checking the values? Polling with Read Attributes?

Its probably better to setup attribute reporting on the values you care about and watch for Report Attribute messages.

Comment: Good idea, i'll get that setup. I'm using software my company develops to check the attributes. We use this against hundreds of devices, but definitely I may just be too impatient.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention, I was checking the devices three sensors so that would be Occupancy, Temperature Measurement, and Illuminance clusters, and then I am watching the primary attribute in each as well as the max, min recorded attributes. The Max, mins are zeroed out which is strange and the other values are sort of at random levels. From what I'm learning there is a bit of something sneaky going on as the device is spewing out data requests on the ZLL profile.

Comment: There's a chance they they either don't measure those values if reporting is not configured or only measure them very infrequently.  Constantly polling battery powered devices will have a big impact on their battery life, so most devices are not designed with it in mind.